# Altium - Simulation of different circuits in the same project. What's the better way?

Tags: simulation, circuits

I'm working on a circuit simulation to understand the effects of the presence or absence of a determinate schematic parts. For example, I have one section with an high-pass and a low-pass filter

[image]

After I simulated this configuration and made my various analysis, I'd like to see what happen if I remove the high-pass filter

[image]

so my first thought was to remove phisicaly the components. But I have many channels like the one in the picture, so it could be frustrating to remove and add, remove and add again if I want to make many simulations.

What's the proper way to menage this situation?

Maybe:

- I could use parameter in the values of the components (C1 and R3 in the example) and set them at `C1 = 1T` and `R3 = 1T` to inhibit their effect. But I think that they contribute anyway in the simulation. Isn't it?
- I could create different sheets whit different circuits. But how can I tell to the simulator to take care only of that sheets in particular? I don't even want to remove and then add sheets from project, it remain intricate for me but it could be the only solution.

What do you think about it?

Comment: Why do you need to simulate more than one channel? It's normal to only simulate a small subset of your entire design. Anyway if you are properly using hierarchical design you may only need to change a child page.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I understand your point and you're right. But anyway the main problem remains because in the schematic the high-pass filter is not the only part I have to modify.

Comment: In normal spice programs, you can parameterize components and step through those parameters in successive runs. I have no idea, though, if altium supports spice parameters

Comment: @pgvoorhees Yes, it supports parameter. But how should I use this feature correctly?

Comment: @thoraz https://techdocs.altium.com/display/AMSE/Parameter+Sweep -- Try this maybe

Comment: @pgvoorhees I know the use of the parameters. I don't want to study the the behavior changing the value of a component, I want to remove temporary the component (a part of circuit in my case) from the simulation.

Comment: @thoraz, the nice thing about spice is that it handles unrealistically large values well. Want a HP filter that works down to effectively everything but DC? 1T is a great value. (as in 1 Tera-farad, and 1 tera-ohm)

Comment: @pgvoorhees Ok. So you agree with my first point for the possible solutions (thanks, due to your comment I realize the errors in the possible values I posted). Isn't it?